# How to determine in which scope is a value in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-5, decimal

I am working on a Asp.Net MVC5 based project. I have campaigns and campaign prizes related to them. For CampaignId = 1, there are three prizes with minimum shopping amount. 
For example:

> Prize-1: MinAmount= 100, Prize= GiftCard10
>
> Prize-2: MinAmount= 200, Prize= GiftCard20
>
> Prize-3: MinAmount= 300, Prize= GiftCard30

On data entry form, I want to check if the amount entered is valid (greater than lowest - 100). Then I want to specify a prize for the amount entered.

If the amount is:

- 180 then prize is GiftCard1
- 280 then prize is GiftCard20
- and so on.

My code:

```
var prizes = db.CampaignPrizes.Where(c => c.CampaignId == cId)
.Select(c => c.MinimumAmount).ToArray();
```

I used a `decimal[]` array and get `MinAmounts` from DB `ToArray`. So I can reach the minimum value.

```
prizes.Min(), prizes.Max()
```

But, how could I specify the correct prize?
Or for whole process, is there an easier way?

Comment: Because I don't have a column named MaximumAmount. For my table, maximum amount means another Prize's minimum amount. So I need to sort the array(ascending) and determine the intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
    string GetPrize(int cId, decimal amount)
    {
        foreach (var campaignPrize in db.CampaignPrizes.Where(c => c.CampaignId == cId).OrderByDescending(x => x.MinimumAmount))
        {
            if (amount > campaignPrize.MinimumAmount)
            {
                return campaignPrize.Prize;
            }
        }

        return "No Gift"; // lesser than or equal to lowest MinimumAmount
    }
```

Comment: I think this is what I want. I just return a JsonPrizeResult class with PrizeName, PrizeId,PrizeAmount and Message. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First you should skip all irrelevant (too big) records:

```
db.CampaingPrizes
  .Where(c => c.CampaingnId == cId)
  .Where(c => c.MinAmount <= amount)
. . .
```

Now you have all similar prizes, but you need max of them:

```
db.CampaingPrizes
  .Where(c => c.CampaingnId == cId)
  .Where(c => c.MinAmount <= amount)
  .Max(c => c.MinAmount);
```

With your data and `amount == 250` at the first step we get `{100, GiftCard10}` and `{200, GiftCard20}`, and at the second step we get `{200, GiftCard20}`.